# Find duplicates in two different tabs

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

This is what I would like to do: Tab A Column A has a mass of numbers, Tab B Column B will have numbers inputted into it. I need to have the Tab B Column B highlight showing a match to a number in Tab A or have a 'Yes' or 'No' answer appear in Tab B column A indicating a match. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Is this for Microsoft Excel?  If so, please add the tag for it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you want to check for a duplicate on the corresponding row in Sheet A or whether any cell in Column A on Sheet A has the value in the corresponding row in Sheet B. I'm assuming your first sheet is named `Sheet1`,  the second sheet is named `Sheet2`, and both data sets start on the first row of their sheet.

#### Testing for duplicates in the entire column

Place `=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,B1)>0,"YES","NO")` in A1 on Sheet2. It will say "YES" or "NO" depending on whether any cell in column A on Sheet1 has the value in B1 on Sheet2. Drag the cell down to adjust it for more rows.

How it works: `COUNTIF` returns the number of cells in a range that satisfy a condition. The range `Sheet1!A:A` includes all cells in column A of Sheet1. They are tested for equality with B1 (which will be adjusted when you drag the cell). The `IF` function returns a value depending on the value of its condition, which is whether the number of cells from `COUNTIF` is nonzero.

#### Highlighting duplicates from the entire column

*Added in response to a comment.*

To highlight based on the presence of duplicates, conditional formatting needs to be applied. Click on the B column header in the second sheet to select the entire column, then choose Manage Rules under the Conditional Formatting button. Add a new rule with the type "Use a formula to determine which cells to format." Press the Format button to select what formatting will be applied. (Highlights can be done with the Fill tab.) Place `=(COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,B1)>0)` in the formula box, then click OK.

#### Testing for duplicates in the corresponding row

Place `=IF(Sheet1!A1=B1,"YES","NO")` in A1 on Sheet2. Again, it says "YES" or "NO" and you can drag it down to more rows.

How it works: the `=` between `Sheet1!A1` (which refers to A1 on Sheet1) and `B1` tests whether those cells' values are equal. `IF` functions the same as above.

Comment: Tried either, not what i was looking for. Wanted to basically have Sheet 2 Column B1 highlight if I type in the same number that was in Sheet 1 Column A:A (entire column).

Comment: @RRobertson I updated my answer, "highlighting duplicates from the entire column" should do what you want.